# recreate(); after setting AppCompatDelegate causes ClassCast exception

Tags: android-studio, android-appcompat, classcastexception, android-night-mode

I am trying to set light mode if the default mode is dark mode in my Intro Activity

Intro.java

```
if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
{
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    this.recreate();
}
```

But this throws an error:

```
2020-10-25 07:04:43.626 9167-9167/com.xxxx.xxxxxx E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
```

I am using

```
Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

Also the theme doesn't update in the Activity.
If anyone knows please help me out on this.

Comment: Answered the Question Over Here [Click me :) ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565156/miui-11-12-theme-switch-results-in-lifecycleexception-classcastexception)

Comment: @RyanM yea, somewhat, since the app works fine one emulator without crashing. i suppose its a rom specific issue.