# MIUI 11/12 Theme Switch Results in LifeCycleException, ClassCastException

Tags: android-studio, classcastexception, android-dark-theme, miui, darkmode

Since MIUI 11/12 Use Its Own Custom Implementation of Dark Mode, using below code results in ClassCastException
and Activity Life Cycle Exception, as DefaultNightMode and LocalNightMode is always Unspecified i.e. -100 instead of 0 or 1.

If anyone has built a workaround for Xiaomi Devices specially for MIUI 11/12. Please Help Me Out On this.

Code Used:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
this.recreate();
```

Error Caused:

```
2020-10-25 07:04:43.626 9167-9167/com.xxxx.xxxxxx E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme 
It says recreating the activity is unnecessary. Depending on the Android version underneath MIUI this might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have looked onto that, The problem is not with Android, its the skin of MIUI that is on top. The app works completely fine on a Stock Android (same api).

Comment: I think the exception is coming from the function `Activity.recreate()`, It seems to give this error on Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself. After fiddling around with it for a week, I did it..

Here is how:

-- Instead of setting android:forceDarkAllowed="false" for each and every Activity.

-- Just goto values.xml and place this in your AppTheme

```
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

It will ask you to create a valuesv29.xml. Create it, and remove the forceDarkAllowed="false" from all activities.

Welcome. :)

Comment: Did you remove the recreate function?

Comment: No @ElNuru, I didn't the problem was that we were changing the theme for each acitivity instead of the the app as a whole. Following the above steps solved this issue.

Comment: @Ayush still not working

Answer (score 1):

Also in jetpack compose just add the line to the theme.xml

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>`

With this target api worked fine for me

Comment: not working.. do u have other solution ?